# Replace one from multiple characters in a python string

Tags: python

I need to modify a word following the rules below:

1-Replace "m" with "T"
2-Replace "i" with "A"
3-Do the modification just one time, randomly

For this I use the code below :

```
word="Comming"
def modification(w):
    modified_word=w.replace('m','T',1).replace('i','A',1)
    return modified_word
print(modification(word))
```

my code replaces "m" one time and "i" one time but when the word contains the two characters, it changes the two characters.

The current result: CoTmAng
The expected result: "CoTming" or "ComTing" or "CommAng" (randomly)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the replacement will effect only the first occurrence of either char, is that ok for you?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if it affect one occurrence of one char it mustn't affect the second char. just one modification

Comment: @SLA, I mean regarding "CoTming" or "ComTing" - only "CoTming" would be done, do you except it?

Comment: What's the randomness in "random"? E.g. same probability of any character being changed or same probability of a "m" vs. "i" being replaced.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I not have a problem if I get Cotming or ComTing or CommAng, but I don't have to change m and i at the same time

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I have no constraints on the probability. The only constraint I have is the number of changes I have to make: it must be equal to 1

Comment: @sbottingota please read the comments I added. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following,

```
import numpy as np
m_pos = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(word) if char == 'm'] # find the positions of all 'm's
i_pos = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(word) if char == 'i'] # find the positions of all 'i's
def modification(w):
    modified_word = [*word] # break down the word into a list of characters
    boolean = np.random.choice([True, False]) 
    # either perform the 'm' or 'i' substitution
    if boolean:
        # Do 'm' substitution
        modified_word[np.random.choice(m_pos)] = 'T' # pick one of the 'm's to substitute
    else:
        # Do 'i' substitution
        modified_word[np.random.choice(i_pos)] = 'A' # pick one of the 'i's to substitute
    return ''.join(modified_word)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason It works! But I don't understand the whole code. I took the idea of the boolean variable and conditions. This is my new code  ` import numpy as np
word="Comming"
def modification(w):
    boolean = np.random.choice([True, False])
    if boolean:
        modified_word=w.replace('m','T',1)
    else:    
        modified_word=w.replace('i','A',1)
    return modified_word
print(modification(word))  `

Comment: @SLA No problem! I think the `.replace()` method only changes the first occurrence of the character you specify.

Comment: yes you are right! Could you add explanations to your code, please? Thank you

Comment: @SLA Just added some comments on the code. There might be a better way to do this, but the source of complication here comes from the fact that `.replace()` either substitutes the first or all the occurrences of a given character, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Apply [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to provide random selection on replacement mapping `{"m": "T", "i": "A"}`:

```
from random import choice

def modify_char(w, repl_map):
    to_repl = choice(list(repl_map.keys()))
    return w.replace(to_repl, repl_map[to_repl], 1)

repl_map = {"m": "T", "i": "A"}
word = "Comming"
print(modify_char(word, repl_map))
```

Comment: I modified this code because there is a problem if the word doesn't contain the two characters to modify: I propose this code: `import numpy as np

def modify_char(w, repl_map):
    l1=list(repl_map.keys())# characters to transform
    
    l2=[*w] # characters of word
    to_repl = np.random.choice(list(set(l1).intersection(l2)))  #chose between charachters to transform that are in the word
    
    print(l1)
    print(l2)
    print(to_repl)
    return w.replace(to_repl, repl_map[to_repl], 1)   #replace just one occurence of the chosed character`